# Не работает BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, парсер

Пытаюсь вывести название автомобиля из страницы с отчетом на Drom'е. Но вместо этого постоянно выводит 'None'.

Такой код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("https://vin.drom.ru/report/v1/50355598-b390-45ca-9a6a-a5174111cbbc_938f0d83de2139ac443b2ad76448baeb318c91ee8fba9117732c7d8354b6e400_1653929093/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find('span', class_='css-7qz070 e1wi99n82'))
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: "Не работает BeautifulSoup" и не будет, сайт динамический.

Comment: И ничего с этим не сделать? Не за что в таких сайтах зацепиться?

Comment: можно скачать отчет в PDF

Comment: С чего вы взяли что у вас в soup есть элемент с классом class_='css-7qz070 e1wi99n82'? Вот вы пишите строку soup.find('span', class_='css-7qz070 e1wi99n82') но не позаботились о том что бы там был элемент который вам нужен, вот объясните мне логику ваших действий.

Comment: Я делаю по примеру из урока. Потому и спрашиваю, что не понимаю логики. Элемент такой есть на странице. Но вывести его не получается. Я и хочу узнать почему